# How to fix duplicated values from BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

I am using a BroadcastReceiver to get battery status such as battery percentage etc. I am also using "never-ending" service that keeps running even if the client closes the app. My problem is that when the client opens the app for the second time the values (battery percentage) in BroadcastReceiver duplicates.

Example from logcat (**1st run**):  *Battery percent: 80%, In foreground: true*

Example from logcat (**app closed from the 1st run**): *Battery percent: 80%, In foreground: false*

Example from logcat (**2nd run**): *Battery percent: 80%, In foreground: false, Battery percent: 80%, In foreground: true*

Example from logcat (**app closed from the 2nd run**): *Battery percent: 80%, In foreground: false, Battery percent: 80%, In foreground: false*

As you can see everything in the BroadcastReceiver repeats itself after the second opening of the app.

I've tried to unregister the BroadcastReceiver but the problem still occurred.

**MainActivity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public boolean inForeground = true;

Intent mServiceIntent;
Context context;

public Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

        float batteryPct = (level / (float)scale);
        int batteryPercentage = (int)((batteryPct)*100);

        Log.i("Battery percent", ""+batteryPercentage+"%!");
        Log.i("In foreground", String.valueOf(inForeground));
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this;
    SensorService mSensorService = new SensorService(getContext());
    mServiceIntent = new Intent(getContext(), mSensorService.getClass());
    if (!isMyServiceRunning(mSensorService.getClass())) {
        startService(mServiceIntent);
    }

    IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    mContext.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, iFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    inForeground = true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    inForeground = false;
    super.onPause();
}

// Services
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            Log.i ("Running Service", true+"!");
            return true;
        }
    }
    Log.i ("Running Service", false+"!");
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    stopService(mServiceIntent);
    Log.i("Main", "onDestroy!");
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

**SensorService class**

```
public class SensorService extends Service {
public SensorService(Context applicationContext) {
    super();
    Log.i("Called", "SensorService!");
}

public SensorService() {
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("Exit", "onDestroy!");
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver.class);
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

**SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver class**

```
public class SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "Ongoing Service!");
    context.startService(new Intent(context, SensorService.class));
}
}
```

The expected output should be **Battery percent: 80%, In foreground: true**, but the actual output is duplicated and looks like **Battery percent: 80%, In foreground: false, Battery percent: 80%, In foreground: true**.

**EDIT**

I already tried this using it in onCreate and onResume:

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
SensorService mSensorService = new SensorService(getContext());
mServiceIntent = new Intent(getContext(), mSensorService.getClass());
    if (isMyServiceRunning(mSensorService.getClass())) {
        mContext.unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

I changed **onDestroy()** to this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    SensorService mSensorService = new SensorService(getContext());
    mServiceIntent = new Intent(getContext(), mSensorService.getClass());
    if (isMyServiceRunning(mSensorService.getClass())) {
        mContext.unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
    }

    stopService(mServiceIntent);
    Log.i("Main", "onDestroy!");
    inForeground = false;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Code now works fine while in foreground, but I'm not getting any readings when the app is in the background.

Comment: How and where did you try to unregister the receiver?

Comment: @DavidWasser I edited the post. I tried to unregister the receiver in onCreate and onResume.

Comment: That can't work. You need to unregister the receiver when your `Activity` finishes. This would be in `onDestroy()` of the root `Activity`. You've registered the `BroadcastReceiver` on the global application `Context`, so it lives on after your `Activity` finishes. When you start a new `Activity`, you create a new `BroadcastReceiver` and register that too.

Comment: @DavidWasser I edited the post again. I presume you meant like that. The code works fine in the foreground but can't get any reading when the app is closed. Do I need to  create a separate BroadcastReceiver for background?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the background"? Is the `Activity` still alive? Or did it get destroyed?

Comment: Also, there are lots of new rules about background `Service`s. Read this: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background To see if these limitations are affecting you, you can run your `Service` as  a "Foreground `Service`" and see if the behaviour changes.

Comment: @DavidWasser Activity did get destroyed, but that triggers Sensor Service for ongoing work in the background (App does not get terminated).

What I want is to monitor battery stats in the foreground AND in the background even when the app is "closed". As I said in the past the problem occurs when app is reopened. Once that happens everything in BroadcastReceiver gets repeated.

Thanks for the link, I will check it out.